# Where is the vmdk actually stored?

Tags: vagrant

From what I understand, Vagrant uses VMDK for disk images. I'm trying to find the VMDK file for a box I have grabbed using `vagrant box add`. I can't find where the actual .box file is stored, either. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**The box file**

`.box` files are stored under the `$HOME/.vagrant.d/boxes` directory. Under this main directory, boxes are classified by name/version/provider.

**VMWare Files for vagrant VM**

when using the VMWare provider, the VM files are stored under the `$PROJECT_DIR/.vagrant/machines/<machine_name/vmware_fusion/<vm_id>` (if you dont specify a name for the VM, `default` will be used

**VirtualBox Files for vagrant VM**

VM will be stored under the default path for VM. You can check by opening VirtualBox preferences panel and review the default location of VM